# Need to input four numbers and output a formatted list

Tags: java, vba, format, code

I've got a handwritten list of about 500 coordinates for sprites on a sprite map in the form X1 Y1 Width Height

I need them outputted into a table with format {X1, Y1, X1+Width, Y1+Height}

I would like to make a VBA macro or something similar to input these numbers with just spaces between and the macro does the math and places them into a table with the above format for me - squiggly brackets included.  Also, the table needs to be five coordinate sets wide before it drops down to a new row.

I started out trying to input the four numbers into a VBA input box, 
but apparently input boxes can only take one variable at a time.  Having four separate input boxes pop up every time would drive me crazy and not save much time in the long run, so I need a new solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about entering them into a spreadsheet? You could have the x values in one column, the y in another, etc. Then in another column write a formula to combine them and output the format you want.

For example if you had a table like:

```
X   Y   Width   Height  Co-ords
3   4   21      13      {3, 4, 24, 17} 
2   6   78      45      {2, 6, 80, 51}
```

You could generate the Co-ords column with the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("{", A2, ", ", B2, ", ", (A2 +C2), ", ", (B2+D2), "}")
```

You can enter this in E2 and then fill down to apply to all cells in that column.

Comment: I like this idea Brad and will go forward with it, but is there a slick way to put it into a 5 by x table?

Comment: Not sure if I follow your question. Do you mean put the X values in row 1, Y values in row 2, etc?

Comment: No I want it in a table with 5 columns basically

Comment: Brad, I'm getting a #VALUE! Error with the format you have above. It seems fine to me, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry I had typed up the original example on my iPad and was using the wrong concatenation symbol. I've updated the answer with a better example and a formula that actually works :)